# Angular: When does app.config get called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension UI using angular. I want to make it so when the user clicks the icon in the upper right the correct screen appears. If the user is not logged in they should go to the login page. If the user is logged in and in drawing mode then they should go to the drawing screen, if they are logged in and not drawing then they should go to the main menu.

My main problem is checking whether or not they are already in drawing mode. I am sending a message to my content scripts to check whether or not I am in drawing mode, but for some reason this callback is never getting called! Very disappointing. I'm not sure when code in app.config gets called; when does it?

**app.js**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  var rootRef = new Firebase(mysterious_url);
  var user = rootRef.getAuth();
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage('isInDrawingMode', {action: 'isInDrawingMode'}, function(response) {
    if (!user) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    } else if (response.inDrawingMode) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/draw');
    } else {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main');
    }
  });
```

**contentscripts.js**

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse){
      // Toggle User Canvas Messages
      if ( request.toggle === 'off' ){
          // toggleUserCanvasOff();
          disableDrawingMode();
          sendResponse({confirm:'canvas turned off'});
      } else if ( request.toggle === 'on' ){
        enableDrawingMode();
          // toggleUserCanvasOn(); 
          sendResponse({confirm:'canvas turned on'});

      // Initialize toggle status for popup button
      } else if ( request.getStatus === true ){
        sendResponse({status:toggle});
      } else if (request.canvasData) { // new Canvas data
        onCanvasData(request.site, request.user, request.data);
      } else if (request.erase){
        eraseUserCanvas();
      } else if (request.changeColor){
        lineColor = request.changeColor;
      } else if (request.image){
        getCurrentUser(function(user){
          var userCanvas = $('.'+ user);
          addOneTimeClickEvent(userCanvas, addImage, request.image);
        });
      } else if (request.action) {
        sendResponse({inDrawingMode: "true"});
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Heys! You can refer about when it's ran in the [docs - under the heading 'Module Loading & Dependencies'](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Comment: You need to specify which tab to send it to the content script. Like: `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response)` : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging